# Use Sub Query in Report shema

Tags: erp, acumatica

I like to generate Report Using Sub-query. 
Is there any way to Use Sub-query in Report Designer?

How to use aggregation functions?

Please guide me with short of example or give me sample screen ID

Comment: I am not found any way to achieve this in Report Designer but, alternative solution is help me to resolve my Issue.

Comment: Create View in SQL >  AddOnProject or Customize Project  > IBqlTable Class for View > Then View will available in Report Designer